# Django I need upload file button only remove choose file and don't need refresh page when upload

Tags: django

I want to upload only button  and don't need refresh when upload how to fix this

model_form_upload.html

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" >Upload</button>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentFile
        fields = ['document']
```

views.py

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        print(form)
    return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: you need to do an ajax request în order to do that

Comment: Do you have an example? Ajax request